# When does Ruby know that a method exists?

Tags: ruby

One question that ran through my mind was how does the Ruby interpreter know that a method exists on a object if the definition is yet to be interpreted? Like, wouldn't it matter whether you define the method first than use it, rather than use it then define it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't know, and it doesn't care - until execution. When a method call statement is executed, the interpreter looks to see if the class (object, not code!) has the named function. If it does not, it looks up the ancestor tree. If it does not find any, it calls the `method_missing` method. If that is not defined, you get your error.

If your function call does not get executed, you will not get any errors.

Answer (score 3):

The interpreter doesn't know about undefined methods ahead of time, for example:

```
o = Object.new
o.foo # => Raises NoMethodError.
class Object
  def foo
    puts "Foo!"
  end
end
o.foo # => prints "Foo!", since the method is defined.
```

However, Ruby has a neat feature called `method_missing` which let's the receiver of a method call take the method name and arguments as separate arguments and handle accordingly as long as no defined method already handles the call.

```
def o.method_missing(sym, *args)
  puts "OK: #{sym}(#{args.inspect})"
  # Do something depending on the value of 'sym' and args...
end
o.bar(1, 2, 3) #=> OK: bar(1, 2, 3)
```

"Method missing" is used by things like active record find methods and other places where it could make sense to have "dynamically defined" functions.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, the interpreter tried to find it when you use it, and since it won't be there, it may fail.

In ( some ) compiled languages, it doesn't matter, because while compiling, the compiler may say "I'll look for this on a second pass"  but I don't think this is the case with Ruby.

Comment: That's not quite true. There are compiled languages (C for example), which are single-pass and you need to declare each function before using it. There is also no reason in general why an interpreted language couldn't use multiple passes and allow you to use a function or method before defining it (and some do). The reason that ruby does not do this, is that in ruby method definition happens at runtime and a method can indeed be defined multiple times or inside a loop, so you can't just single out the method definitions in a first pass as they interact with the other code.